Trouble after cin.ignore() - next line is missing the 1st letter
I have a problem with cin.ignore(). I want to receive 2 strings from the user. I get the first string correctly. And I do cin.ignore() after that, but when I want to receive the other string it doesn't read the first letter. What should I do to solve this problem?
See that Ps doesn't have s of salam in the 2nd string.


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

You should not be calling cin.ignore() in this situation.  The 1st cin.getline() call has already read (and discarded) the line break that you are apparently trying to ignore, so you are actually ignoring the 1st letter of the 2nd line before cin.getline() has a chance to read it.
You should call cin.ignore() only after a read operation has left something behind that is worth ignoring (for example, ignoring left-over input after reading formatted input via operator>> - see Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?).  That is not the case here.
Just remove the call to cin.ignore(). You don't need it in this example. Do not call cin.ignore() unnecessarily before the next read operation.
Since you are using char[] strings, the only time it makes sense to call cin.ignore() is if cin.get() or cin.getline() fails because the user's input is longer than your char[] arrays can hold. In that situation, cin's failbit state would be set. You would need to call cin.clear() to remove that state before calling cin.ignore() to remove any left-over input.

That being said, consider using std::string instead of char[], eg:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    string text, search;
    getline(cin, text);
    getline(cin, search);
    ...
}

